# How to draw a imageview into a canvas in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, canvas, android-canvas, android-drawable

Hi i want to draw a imageview into canvas in android studio

I found this code that draws a drawable but i want it to draw a imageview

```
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable
                (R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        drawable.setBounds(20, 30, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+20, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
```

and this is what i want it to draw

```
ImageView thisisImg= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
```

how do i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `getDrawable()` from ImageView.
Your example would turn into:

```
ImageView thisisImg= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

Drawable drawable = thisisImg.getDrawable();

drawable.setBounds(20, 30, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+20, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
drawable.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: What if I want to draw the imageView using fitCenter within a given bounds? If I use this technique, the image is stretched to fit the bounds.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat you should ask a separate question, not as a comment here. I am no longer developing for Android so not capable to answer anymore.

Comment: How to draw at positions `x` and `y`?